# CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM abort() has been called

Tags: opencv

I get error :abort() has been called

```
Mat M = cvarrToMat(img);
int n = features->total;
Point point;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    point = *CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(Point, features, i);
    circle(M, point, 2, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
}
```

Comment: Why are sou using deprecated C OpenCV API? is it really needed or can you use the C++

Comment: Thx, This is my job requirement . I have solved my problem